# How to target multiple items for Drag and Drop program in Javascript using a single function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a **pure** Javascript program for Dragging and Dropping items(ex: Divs) from one place to another(same page). I have coded the application but in a not-so-good manner. I'v written a function which on onmouseup event selects the id of the div and onmousedown drops it wherever the mouse is. But, I am using the same function and calling it multiple times for every div I am making. So, I am looking for an efficient way using which I need to call the function only once and can use it for calling multiple divs to be dragged and dropped.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="block1"> </div>
    <div id="block2"> </div>
    <div id="block3"> </div>
    <div id="block4"> </div>
    <div id="block5"> </div>
    <div id="block6"> </div>
    <div id="block7"> </div>
    <div id="block8"> </div>
    <div id="block9"> </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function() {
   // For Block 1...
    var el = document.getElementById('block1');
    var mover = false, x, y, posx, posy, first = true;
    el.onmousedown = function() {
        mover = true;
    };
    el.onmouseup = function() {
        mover = false;
        first = true;
    };
    el.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (mover) {
            if (first) {
                x = e.offsetX;
                y = e.offsetY;
                first = false;
            }
            posx = e.pageX - x;
            posy = e.pageY - y;
            this.style.left = posx + 'px';
            this.style.top = posy + 'px';
        }
    };

    // For Block 2...
    var el = document.getElementById('block2');
    var mover = false, x, y, posx, posy, first = true;
    el.onmousedown = function() {
        mover = true;
    };
    el.onmouseup = function() {
        mover = false;
        first = true;
    };
    el.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (mover) {
            if (first) {
                x = e.offsetX;
                y = e.offsetY;
                first = false;
            }
            posx = e.pageX - x;
            posy = e.pageY - y;
            this.style.left = posx + 'px';
            this.style.top = posy + 'px';
        }
    };
 ....
}
```

Comment: Why have you tagged jquery if you aren't using it and dont want to use it?

Comment: You said this works? Doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: @zfrisch yes man, it works.. If I call the above declared function 9 times for every div id it works.. But I don't want to call it 9 times.. Just one time..

Comment: Have you tried getting all your elements with something like document.querySelectorAll() and then looping through them?